# Handling login form in modal using web2py

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication, web2py

I have been trying to make modal login form , but as validation of credentials are done after pressing submit the dialog box gets closed , and when I open it again I get to see errors like - invalid username or password .

Here is my jQuery-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#loginForm').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    icon: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        username: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The username is required'
                }
            }
        },
        password: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The password is required'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Can I get any basic functional implementation of modal login , which is using ajax where modal box closes only on successful login.

Comment: This example can be helpful: http://formvalidation.io/examples/modal/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Though i don't have a complete working sample (because i don't own a copy of the framework).

Check out the [remote validator](http://formvalidation.io/validators/remote/) which provides exactly what you want. You will have to have two validators on the web2py side though. Use the [sending dynamic data](http://formvalidation.io/validators/remote/#sending-dynamic-data-example) example to send both the username and password when checking the password.

On the serverside use code similar to:

```python
def test_email(): 
    found = db(db.auth_user.email == request.post_vars.email).count()
    return response.json(dict(valid=found > 0))


def test_credentials():
    records = db(db.auth_user.email == request.post_vars.email).select()
    if not records:
        return response.json(dict(valid=False))
    else:
        hashed_password = db.auth_user.password.validate(request.post_vars.password)[0]
        hashes_equal = records.first().password == hashed_password
        return response.json(dict(valid=hashes_equal))
```

(mind you web2py defaults to email instead of username, so i used that instead. you can easily change your fieldnames)

Alternatively alter a sample from the [documentation found here](http://formvalidation.io/developing/#dynamic-message) in which you can perform some ajax in the `// do you logic` part switch on the result received to have your modal respond correctly:

```js
(function($) {
    FormValidation.Validator.validatorName = {
        validate: function(validator, $field, options) {
            // ... Do your logic checking
            if (...) {
                return {
                    valid: true,    // or false
                    message: 'The error message'
                }
            }

            return {
                valid: false,       // or true
                message: 'Other error message'
            }
        }
    };
}(window.jQuery));
```

This approach allows for other libraries, like [jquery-jsonrpc2.0](https://github.com/hagino3000/jquery-jsonrpc2.0) to shine and ease development.